# Cannot stop background music (Swift 3, Xcode 8)

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode

I have an instance of `AVAudioPlayer` run when the view loads.  From another `ViewController` I have a `UISwitch` to stop the music.  I can receive the `Bool` from the switch and see it calling the correct function in the `console` but I cannot get the music to stop playing.  I have tried to stop, pause, and change volume but to no avail. When the app is shut down (double tap home and swipe up) and the switch state was left off, the music will not play.  If you toggle the switch on the music will play but will not stop.

Code:

```
var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

let optionDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    do{

        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "backgroundmusic", ofType: "wav")
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
        player.volume = 0.2

        if optionDefaults.value(forKey: "musicOn") != nil  {

            let musicOn: Bool = optionDefaults.value(forKey: "musicOn") as! Bool
            if musicOn == false  {

                print("********** Music is off **********")
                player.stop()

            }

            else {

                print("********** Music is On **********")
                player.play()

            }  
        } 
    } catch {
       print("AVPlayer did not initialize")
    }

    player.numberOfLoops = -1
}
```

******* code for switch ********

```
 let optionDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

 @IBOutlet weak var musicOnOff: UISwitch!

 var musicOn : Bool = true

 @IBAction func switchToGame(sender: UIButton) {


    if musicOnOff.isOn{

        musicOn = true
        optionDefaults.set(musicOn, forKey: "musicOn")

    }

    if musicOnOff.isOn == false{

        musicOn = false
        optionDefaults.set(musicOn, forKey: "musicOn")

    }}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

if optionDefaults.value(forKey: "musicOn") != nil  {

    let musicOn: Bool = optionDefaults.value(forKey: "musicOn") as! Bool
    if musicOn == false  {

        musicOnOff.isOn = false

    }

    else{

        musicOnOff.isOn  = true

    }
}}
```

Comment: can you include the code from the switch toggle? it seems like the viewcontroller only checks the state of the switch when it is loaded once, which wouldn't let you to pause the music.

Comment: @DaneJordan, edited post to add switch toggle code

Answer (score 0):

You are playing the music only when view loading completes.If You want to stop and play when switch toggles just call palyOrStopMusic method on toggle switch action

```
var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

let optionDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

override func viewDidLoad() {

super.viewDidLoad()
     playOrStopMusic()
  }

func playOrStopMusic(){
 do{

        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "backgroundmusic", ofType: "wav")
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
        player.volume = 0.2

        if optionDefaults.value(forKey: "musicOn") != nil  {

            let musicOn: Bool = optionDefaults.value(forKey: "musicOn") as! Bool
            if musicOn == false  {

                print("********** Music is off **********")
                player.stop()

            }

            else {

                print("********** Music is On **********")
                player.play()

            }  
        } 
    } catch {
       print("AVPlayer did not initialize")
    }

    player.numberOfLoops = -1
}
```

******* code for switch ********

```
 let optionDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

 @IBOutlet weak var musicOnOff: UISwitch!

 var musicOn : Bool = true

 @IBAction func switchToGame(sender: UIButton) {


    if musicOnOff.isOn{
        musicOn = true
        optionDefaults.set(musicOn, forKey: "musicOn")
    }else{
        musicOn = false
        optionDefaults.set(musicOn, forKey: "musicOn")
    }

    playOrStopMusic()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playOrStopMusic()
}
```

Comment: That did not work, and now when I go to the options ViewController it starts the music again so it overlays